# How to request increase of DLLs via the environment variable R_MAX_NUM_DLLS?

Tags: r, dll

> By default, the maximum number of DLLs that can be loaded is now 614 when the OS limit on the number of open files allows or can be increased, but less otherwise (but it will be at least 100). A specific maximum can be requested via the environment variable `R_MAX_NUM_DLLS`, which has to be set (to a value between 100 and 1000 inclusive) before starting an R session

This is from the notes section of `?dyn.load`.

As a beginner I do not understand how this is done practically. I can see a file names `R.environ` in `C:\Users\r0700093\Documents\R\R-3.4.3` which I can open in notepad. What should I do then?

Comment: What is "an R session"? Can you provide more context? Why do you need to load more DLLs?

Comment: Please tag the question with `R` if that is the programming language. iirc, Windows uses a `set NAME=VALUE` syntax for setting environment variables from the command line. Check your `R.environ` file for something that looks like name-value pairs. Then add another one, with R_MAX_NUM_DLLS as name and 666 (or some other number) as value.